# Is it safe to access (read) a bit from a bitset (C++) which may be modified by a different thread

Tags: c++, stl, thread-safety, bit-manipulation

Is this type of operation considered safe? (in other words no chance of reading some bogus intermediate value if the bitset is being modified on a different thread)? Specifically I'm only interested in whether the read is safe, in other words, I am not asking whether it's safe to write to a bitset from two separate threads.

eg: Will thread 1 reliably get the current state of bit 5 regardless of whether other bits in bs are being set/cleared at the same time?

```
std::bitset<64> bs;

//thread 1:
bool val;
val=bs.test(5);
// ...

//thread 2:
// set/clear a few bits
bs.set(1);
bs.set(3);
bs.set(5);
bs.reset(6);
// ...
```

Comment: No Standard Library containers are thread safe in the face of concurrent reads and writes.

Comment: Are you thinking you could read _a half a bit_? No such thing. If thread A is waiting for Thread B to set by reading the bit, that is fine. The bigger picture may be in trouble.

Comment: @lakeweb my concern is not reading half a bit, but whether thread B setting a *different* bit might temporarily cause the bit thread A is reading to be in a different state.

Comment: Dont use bits then, but `std::atomic<bool>`, your microoptimizations could cost you big headache

Comment: A `bitset<64>` will fit nicely in a CPU register. How do you know when thread 2 cares to write the value to memory?

Comment: If more than one thread accesses a data object and at least one of those threads writes to that data object you have a data race, i.e., undefined behavior. Whether or not this is "safe" depends on how you define "safe".

Comment: Just to confirm, I traced into the disassembly. There is no intermediate going on with the shared memory. Reads but only one write. But thread shared memory takes careful planning. It is about the bigger picture. For instance racing as is pointed out. Deadlock on the other hand, [you have to make a good plan](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&q=memory+sharing+between+threads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `std::bitset` that way is **not** thread safe.

This is what the standard says about accessing a bitset (§ 20.9.2.2-51):

> For the purpose of determining the presence of a data race, any access or update through the resulting reference potentially accesses or modifies, respectively, the entire underlying bitset.

Therefore, writing to a bitset object while reading from it in another thread of execution is a data race (which triggers undefined behavior). Even if all threads access the bitset object using a different index.

Answer (score 1):

Bitset does not offer atomic modification, so changes of bits may latch older values in nearby bits.

If there was a reset(5) that may mean thread 1 never sees the set bit.

Answer (score 0):

No STL container is thread-safe. While you will not get an intermediate value, you might end up ignoring a set of the value if the threads are not synchronized. Use `atomic` operations.

Comment: The standard containers are thread safe in the sense that no elements will be modified if not directly accessible. ie `std::vector vec{1, 2, 3}; std::thread{[&]() mutable { vec[0]++; }}.detach(); vec[1]++;` is legal

Comment: @PasserBy I doubt whether that applies to `std::bitset<64>`. On my platform, the size is 8, which allows for 8 different addresses. Unlikely you can modify 64 bits concurrently.with, let's say, 64 threads

Comment: @LWimsey Funny thing, bitset isn't considered a container in the standard.

Comment: @PasserBy  that makes sense then